# Prove or disprove: $f(x)=\ln(x^2)$ is surjective or injective

Tags: functions, logarithms

> Consider the function $f:(0,\infty)→(−\infty,\infty)$ defined by $f(x)=\ln(x^2)$. Prove or disprove each of the following statements.
>
> 1. The function $f$ is surjective.
> 2. The function $f$ is injective.

Any help would be nice

Comment: You tagged it `proof-verification`. Where is the proof to verify?

Comment: Note that $\ln(x^2)=2\ln x$. You know how the graph of $y=\ln x$ is so basically you know how the graph of $y=\ln(x^2)$ looks like. Can you see if $f(x)$ is injective? surjective?

Comment: This isn't a homework site. Share your work/thoughts on the problem to get a favourable response.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show the following much more interesting fact:

For a composition of functions $f\circ g$ it holds:

- if $f\circ g$ is injective, then $f$ is.
- if $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $g$ is.

Both can be easily proved by contradiction.